# Python | TkInter | Add/Delete Buttons/Rows in a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, button, destroy, tkinter.optionmenu

I have a GUI with an Option Menu that has a list of numbers (1:8). When a number is selected, an equal amount of buttons will be populated below. When those buttons are selected, a label next to it will be generated with the choice of folder locations. All that works great.

However, I want to be able to alter the number of buttons dynamically. When I increase the number of buttons, buttons are added, which is what I expect. However, I can't figure out how to remove buttons if say, I originally select 8, but reduce it to 4.

I'd also like to be able to increase/decrease the number dynamically.

I've already tried using grid_forget(), grid_remove() and destroy to try to remove that line/button/grid location off the grid, but nothing works.

Here's my original code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, StringVar, filedialog, OptionMenu
from functools import partial

def main():
    # Create a GUI to select the number of video folders

    # root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1200x500")
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.title("Assign Videos")

    class AssignVideos:
        def __init__(self, master):
            """initializes the GUI with a dropdown to select the number of video cameras.
            The selection will then create an equal number of prompts to select where the data
             for each camera is stored"""

            # Header to select the number of reference video cameras
            self.number_of_cams_selection_header = ttk.Label(
                text="Number of Videos:"
            )
            self.number_of_cams_selection_header.grid(column=0, row=0)

            # Create an option menu with which to select the number of reference video cameras
            self.select_number_of_cams = OptionMenu(
                root,
                StringVar(root, value=" "),
                *[str(num) for num in range(1, 9)],
                command=self.create_inputs,
            )
            self.select_number_of_cams.grid(column=1, row=0)

            # Define variables that are going to be used later
            self.number_of_cams = int
            self.folder_path_label = {}
            self.folder_path_button = {}
            self.folder_path = {}
            self.folder_path_selection = {}

        def create_inputs(self, _):
            """Generates the equal number of folder selection inputs for the user to select the location of the VVIDs"""
            self.number_of_cams = int(self.select_number_of_cams["text"])
            for num in range(self.number_of_cams):
                # Creates the label to select the folder path
                self.folder_path_button[num] = ttk.Button(
                    root,
                    text=f"Select the Folder for Camera # " f"{num + 1}: ",
                    command=partial(self.select_folder, num)
                )
                self.folder_path_button[num].grid(column=1, row=num + 1)

        def select_folder(self, num):
            """Places Buttons on the screen to select the folder"""
            self.folder_path_selection[num] = filedialog.askdirectory()
            self.folder_path[num] = ttk.Label(root, text=self.folder_path_selection[num])
            self.folder_path[num].grid(column=2, row=num+1)


    _ = AssignVideos(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You have already saved those buttons and labels into dictionaries, so you can just go through those dictionaries to destroy the buttons and labels at the beginning of `create_inputs()`.

Comment: Hint: ```for num, button in self.folder_path_button.items(): button.destroy()```